# Is there a way to default the Export CSV file origin of dataloader to UTF-8?

Tags: data-loader, data-export, format

I export Salesforce data out to CSV on a frequent basis especially in a foreign language like Mandarin.

Even if I check the UTF-8 options on Dataloader settings :

[image]

The file that gets exported out from Dataloader is a file without any extensions.
What I usually do is rename the file to append '.csv'. But to my surprise all the Chinese characters end up becoming like 'å®æ³¢é¦™æ ¼é‡Œæ‹‰å¤§é…’åº—'

So I have to do the lengthy way of opening up a blank Excel -> go 'Data' tab -> From Text/CSV -> Choose the file I want to format. Then I noticed that the file churned out by dataloader is always **Western European**.

[image]

Any ideas how to default the files churned out by Dataloader to UTF-8?

Dataloader version : 45.0.0

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the encoding before you can see the proper character displayed in Excel.
Excel can display the unicode characters correctly if the format is UTF-8 with BOM/Unicode

You can use Sublime Text, vscode or even Notepad (or any editor that supports this):

- In Sublime Text: File | Save with Encoding
- In vscode: View | Command Palette | Change File Encoding | Save with Encoding
- In Notepad: File | Save As (choose encoding as UTF-8 or Unicode)

Open in Excel.